# Defunct online mapping service with abstract or simplified route map

Tags: web-mapping

Back when it was common for people to print paper driving directions from a website like MapQuest (say, around 2000) I remember one of the mapping services offering an alternative format for the route map, which simplified each road to a straight line, in much the same way that subway maps often simplify the geometry of the routes.

In terms of the visual appearance on the page, this style of map always reminded me of a sentence diagram:

[image: a sentence diagram]

Does anybody remember what mapping service offered this style of map, and what they called it? Does anyone still have any examples, or know of a service that still offers this style of map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are thinking of LineDrive, from my dusty copy of Mapping Hacks Hack #6 Making Route Maps Easier to Read discusses LineDrive which was originally part of MapBlast.com and had been bought by Microsoft. The original paper (Rendering Effective Route Maps: Improving Usability Through Generalization, Maneesh Agrawala & Chris Stolte) the work was based on can still be [found online](https://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/routemaps/).

Here is the example route that was shown in the book.

[image]

Comment: Yes! That's what I was thinking of, and both LineDrive and MapBlast ring a bell. Thank you!